# Upgrade MAMP to MAMP PRO config errors

Tags: mamp

I've been using MAMP for a few years and have upgraded to MAMP PRO using the "Try MAMP Pro" button. It's v3.0.7.73. I am having somekind of basic config error. It's manifested differently on my Drupal, WordPress, and Joomla site.

In WordPress it goes to the install page and wants to reinstall WordPress.

In Drupal I get a MySQL error:

PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000] [1049] Unknown database 'drupalopenatrium' in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Drupal-OpenAtrium/includes/lock.inc).

In Joomla it's another MySQL error:

Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: No database selected SQL=DELETE FROM `f1w2j_session` WHERE `time` < '1427392321'

If I quit the MAMP Pro app and launch the MAMP app it all works fine. I searched for a solution but can't find one. Has to be a config issue. I have too many sites to want to reinstall. What did I miss? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like I may have setup MAMP Pro once before. In /Library/Application Support/appsolute/db/ there are databases that have been deleted for quite some time. Probably over a year. And there's databases missing. Any suggestions on how I might reconcile this snarled up mess?

Comment: Yes, this had to do with a previously installed MAMP Pro. The solution was to rename the enclosing database folder, mysql, to something different. MAMP Pro then replaced the databases with the correct data. There's a good video of it on the MAMP video channel. Here's the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wBnHo1o4W8Q